# EditText on touch

Tags: android, touch, android-edittext

I have a DateTimePicker with a little "amount" editext that I save the Sharedpref
but for some reason if I "touch" the EditText and enter the amount in manually, the text is black and doesn't transfer to the TextView, if using the imagebuttons `increase` and `decrease` the editText will work as intended. If I enter the dates and times in this manner though it does work, what am I missing?

```
ImageButton increase = (ImageButton)mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.increase);
increase.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){


amountt++;
amountText = Integer.toString(amountt);
amountedit.setHint(amountText);
amnt.setText(amountText);



editor.putString("numbers", amountText);
editor.commit();

    }
});
ImageButton decrease = (ImageButton)mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.decrease);
decrease.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v){




      amountt--;
      amountText = Integer.toString(amountt);
      amountedit.setHint(amountText);
      amnt.setText(amountText);

      editor.putString("numbers", amountText);
      editor.commit();

    }
});
```

The relevant EditText info

```
amountedit=(EditText)mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.amountedit);
```

The TextView it displays to

```
amnt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.amountText);
```

The XML of EditText

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/amountedit"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:key = "amntkey"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="62dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:persistent="true" />
```

The complete java activity it takes place:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.iimed.www.DateTimePicker.DateWatcher;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard.Key;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CaAdd extends Activity implements DateWatcher,OnClickListener{
Button button_click;
int amountt = 0;

String amountText;
String number = "numbers";
TextView amnt;
TextView dateResult, date2;
int hrs,min;
SharedPreferences pref;
String time = "time";
String get;
String sTime;
String amount ;
EditText amountedit;
String result_string;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.datetimeactivity);
dateResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);

date2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
 button_click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setbtn);
 pref = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
button_click.setOnClickListener(this);
 amnt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.amountText);
 pref = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 amountText = Integer.toString(amountt);
 amount = amnt.toString();
 get = pref.getString("numbers",amountText);
sTime = pref.getString("time", result_string);
 amnt.setText(get);
 date2.setText(sTime) ; 
}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){


    case R.id.setbtn:




final Dialog mDateTimeDialog = new Dialog(this);
// Inflate the root layout
final RelativeLayout mDateTimeDialogView = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.date_time_dialog, null);
// Grab widget instance
final DateTimePicker mDateTimePicker = (DateTimePicker) mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.DateTimePicker);
mDateTimePicker.setDateChangedListener(this);
mDateTimePicker.initData();
amountedit=(EditText)mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.amountedit);
ImageButton increase = (ImageButton)mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.increase);
increase.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){


        Editor editor = pref.edit();

amountt++;
amountText = Integer.toString(amountt);
amountedit.setHint(amountText);
amnt.setText(amountText);

String amount =amnt.toString();

editor.putString("numbers", amountText);
editor.commit();

    }
});
ImageButton decrease = (ImageButton)mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.decrease);
decrease.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v){



        Editor editor = pref.edit();
      amountt--;
      amountText = Integer.toString(amountt);
      amountedit.setHint(amountText);
      amnt.setText(amountText);
String edi = amountedit.toString();
      editor.putString("numbers", amountText);
      editor.commit();

    }
});

Button setDateBtn = (Button)mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.SetDateTime);

setDateBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(CaAdd.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(CaAdd.this, 2,    intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
           AlarmManager alm=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


            Editor editor = pref.edit();

            hrs=mDateTimePicker.getHour();
            min=mDateTimePicker.getMinute();
            Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hrs);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            alm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);

         mDateTimePicker.clearFocus();
           result_string = 
         String.valueOf(mDateTimePicker.getHour()) + ":" + String.valueOf(mDateTimePicker.getMinute());


          if(mDateTimePicker.getHour() > 12) result_string = result_string + "PM";
         else result_string = result_string + "AM";
         date2.setText(result_string);
         editor.putString("time",result_string);
          editor.commit();

         mDateTimeDialog.dismiss();
         }
         });




Button cancelBtn = (Button)mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.CancelDialog);

cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
mDateTimePicker.reset();
mDateTimeDialog.cancel();
}
});



Button resetBtn = (Button)mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.ResetDateTime);
resetBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
mDateTimePicker.reset();
}
});

mDateTimeDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

mDateTimeDialog.setContentView(mDateTimeDialogView);

mDateTimeDialog.show();}}




public void onDateChanged(Calendar c) {
Log.e("","" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + " " + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+ " " + c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
String result_string =String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)  + "/" + String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) + "/" + String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.YEAR));

dateResult.setText(null);







}}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but still your question isn't clear, can you explain more?! and the increase and decrease ImageButton, are they the same `up` and `down` button you mentioned above?!

Comment: Yeah sorry, they are the same I will edit them. So pretty much the input for the EditText saves to my editor and displays on the desired textView IF I use the `increase` and `decrease` ImageButtons I created for it, but for some reason I am unable to save or display the input if I enter the value by directly clicking the edittext field and entering say `18`.

Comment: so what do you want to do is when you finish editing the `EditText` you want it to directly add the value to a `TextView` without clicking on a button?!

Comment: No no, the `setbtn` adds the value through SharedPrefs etc, the only problem I am having is when I enter the EditText value  by directly clicking the edittext it doesn't save/display etc, however if I enter the EditText value using my `increase` & `decrease` buttons its saves/displays just fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't clear, you should post code about that EditText you're talking about.

BTW, to get what you would like, you can try to do Sharedpref's edit & commit

when your EditText's text changed, although it's a bad design...

You need a Text change listener

```
EditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
  {}

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
  {}

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
  {}
});
```

Comment: I updated the original question, I hope it is enough, it's everything on the editText.

Comment: You need a text change listener to do things when EditText's text been changed...and also, that could make something like race condition or looping event with your ImageButton did, you need few more code to overcome that.

Comment: I've been trying this `amountedit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{`
I'm not sure where to put the rest or what to put in them?

Comment: Just do what you did in your ImageButton's onClick, but make a flag if EditText's text ware changed by your ImageButton, don't do things again. That's all :-)